# jquery plugin tutorial confusing, cannot see init parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm currently exploring [jQuery's plugin authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) and:

```
var methods = {
    init : function(options) {
        console.log(options);
        return this.each(function() {
            console.log(options);
        });
    }
};
```

the tutorial said that to maintain *chainability* (which i may use), i should `return this.each()`. i see that calling `$('div').myPlugin({'test':'test'})` calls the init function and logs in the console `options`. however, i don't seem to see `options` inside `return this.each()`.

can someone explain why is that so? is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .each() method of jQuery has a pre-defined set of parameters, so the first parameter will be treated as the index of the current element. So "options" will be replaced with the index. There is no need to hand-over "options" to the function, though, it will be automatically available as the function creates a closure.

```
return this.each(function() {
    console.log(options);
});
```

Hint: You are not actually returning this.each() ... technically you are just returning "this"

Comment: thanks for that explanation. i'm still trying to understand closures that's why i can't see if a block of code is a closure or not.